# F1 key to run macro

Tags: vba, excel

How can I assign <kbd>F1</kbd> key to macro in excel instead of 'excel help'? I see many answers to this question, but they do not work in excel 2013/2016.

I need solutions like this, but for new Excel:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1798-excel-disable-f1-key.html
https://excel.tips.net/T002089_Disabling_the_F1_Key.html

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Public Sub TestMe()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", "RunMe"
End Sub

Public Sub UnTestMe()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}"
End Sub

Public Sub RunMe()
    Debug.Print Now
End Sub
```

If you run `TestMe`, it would assign <kbd>F1</kbd> to `RunMe`. To unassign it, run `UnTestMe`. In general, you may consider using <kbd>F1</kbd> with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> like this:

```
Application.OnKey "^{F1}", "F1_CtrlMacro"
Application.OnKey "%{F1}", "F1_AltMacro"
Application.OnKey "+{F1}", "F1_ShiftMacro"
Application.OnKey "{F1}", "F1_OnlyMacro"
```

**Edit:**

To assign it from the beginning, add the following in the **ThisWorkbook**:[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.OnKey "{F1}", "RunMyCode"
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there way to assign it without need of running macro? Just open Excel and it is under F1 from beginning.

Comment: Nice thing is that, as I just tested, this is session specific, no need to remove it in `Workbook_BeforeClose` :). Do you confirm?

Comment: @A.S.H - No need to confirm, I believe you. :) But in general, I like removing these kind of stuff, cos you never know how many Excels the user has opened and what exactly s/he is doing in them.

Comment: @Vityata lol I know you believe me :P but I was looking for consolidating my quick test :)

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor and helps others, with a similar problem.

Comment: @A.S.H - ok, consider it consolidated. :)

Comment: Anyone who goes to the trouble of including a **big helpful arrow** in their answer deserves the points! ;)

Answer (score 2):

To disable the current keystroke set to <kbd>F1</kbd>

use following VBA code

```
Sub disableF1()
Application.OnKey "{F1}", ""
End Sub
```

then to assign it to a macro you made

```
Public Sub RunMyMacro()

    Application.OnKey "{F1}", "RunMyCode"

End Sub
```

here is an example of the macro you want it to run:

```
Public Sub RunMyCode

    MsgBox "This is my macro to run!"

End Sub
```

Have a nice day

Regards Xsi